# Inserting data into Ms access Table Java

Tags: sql

For inserting database in ms access can I use condition where to insert. like...  statement.execute("insert into student (Name)  values  (1)  where ID=4");

Comment: NO you can't. Use `UPDATE` statement instead.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have an  existing record with ID=4 and you want the name value to be populated there? If yes, then you'll need an update statement to do that instead of Insert